# Foreign Key in SQL to pivot table - database design

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Im developing an application that allows to upload music from certain category (sample,full song,chorus..etc) and certain genre (rock, pop, rap...etc) and since I can have a sample from any genre and any genre can have any category I made a many to many relationship with it's pivot table. So far so good, but now I want make an audio file table that has a category and a genre...it is a good practice to relate it directly to the id of the pivot table? or should I add category_id and genre_id to the audio_files table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following.  This each audio file can have its own category defined and its own genre.

[image]